# Want to use image in datagrid to show active and inactive user?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

i have a database of country table. sql 2005 like,

```
country_id  country_name   region       area    population   gdp        status
   84        indi         asia      3432     3423           343         Active
   85        U.k          Europe   43432     3243          2343         Inactive
```

I want to user image of active and inactive instead of text in my datagrid .. not in database.. in database there is text only..

so.. i am using .net 2005 .. i want to bind image with status.. and whenever i changed active to inactive or inactive to active.. image will be change . according that..

i am using C# as code behind language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to add an image column like that :

```
<asp:ImageField 
    DataImageUrlField="status" 
    DataImageUrlFormatString="~/images/{0}.jpg">
</asp:ImageField>
```

And you should have two images like active.jpg and inactive.jpg in your images folder.

By the way if you have null values in your status column don't forget to set **NullImageUrl** property for them.

**EDIT :** Actually I see you're looking for DataGrid, I missed it, here is the datagrid way with template column :

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status", "~/images/{0}.jpg") %>' />
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

And this one with the asp:image server control :

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgStatus" 
        ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status", "~/images/{0}.jpg") %>' />
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I can't get your question ? But sorting will be no problem. if you set the right location of the images, it should work well.

Comment: <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText=" Status" DataField="status"  SortExpression="status" ItemStyle-Width="140" ></asp:BoundColumn>

this is my column of status.. where i put you code.. into templet or where?

Comment: No, just replace your column with mine. Add the properties to mine column too : HeaderText=" Status" SortExpression="status" ItemStyle-Width="140"

Comment: can u set this line with your img src line.. because.. img src is not suitable.. for datagrid.. its given error..

<asp:image   />

what will be used inside.. can u tell me.. pls

Answer (score 1):

ImageField was introduced in ASP.Net 2.0 for GridView. [Here's a good article explaining it (with screenshots).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)

To display an image in a column in a DataGrid in ASP.NET 1.x you have to use a TemplateColumn with an Image Web control inside the TemplateColumn.

Comment: but i am using... datagrid.. thats why?